# Why does standing on a wire produce these tension forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I don't need help solving the problem. But I do need convincing that there are two tension forces that act in the way given in the image.

If the person wasn't standing on the wire, but instead attached to it, then I could see how the two tension forces would point in those directions. But I don't see how standing on the wire produces tensions pointing in those directions.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct to question the idea that standing on the wire "produces" forces.
Tension forces act at all points along the length of the wire because the wire has been stretched between the two end supports. It is a "tight"-rope.
Every small portion of the tight wire is in equilibrium because two equal and opposite tension forces act, directed along the length of the wire.
Those forces exist at every portion of the wire before the person is introduced.

When we add a person, standing on the wire, or hanging from the wire, or clinging to the wire, the effect of the downwards acting weight of the person is to displace the wire sideways, at the point of contact with the wire.
And now, given that the wire changes direction at the point of contact, we have created a condition in which the two "equal and opposite" tension forces acting on that small portion of the wire are no longer opposite. They are inclined upwards, pointing along the directions of the wire at each side of the person.

So the person does not cause the tension forces. The person causes the sideways displacement of the wire, and that wire direction angle change causes the two forces to act at different angles, and that results in a resultant upwards force.

We could draw equal and opposite tesion forces at every point along the straight portions of the wire. But since those pairs of forces sum to zero nett force on each small portion of the wire we don't usually do that. Only at the sideways change in direction do those forces become worth paying attention to, and so we draw them on the diagram.

Comment: Hey bro. Thanks you cleared up a lot of my misconceptions... Only thing im not quite sure about is you say the weight of the person displaces the wire sideways? Don't you mean downwards?

Answer (score 1):

It may help to think of the wire as a chain with separate links. Each link pulls on the link next to it.

The walker is standing on a link. The two links connected to it pull on that link.

It works the same with a wire. Each short piece of wire is pulled on by the pieces of wire next to it.

---

The tension forces pull along the wire. The person isn't stretching the wire. He is pushing down on it with his weight. The short piece of wire under his foot is being stretched by the pieces of wire that are attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

With no person on the wire, a massless wire is horizontal as there is no force downward on the wire.  When a person stands, or hangs, on the wire without moving, an upward force must be provided on the person to counter the downward force of gravity on the person.  That upward force on the person must be provided by the wire, and the wire must sag to provide that force.

Do a force balance on the segment of wire under the person's foot to keep that segment in equilibrium (no net force).  Consider the weight of the person, and the tension on each end of the segment from the part of the wire connected to each end of the segment.